# mysql syntax error near '', how can i correct it?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL when I meet an error executing query below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_apply(
IN in_username VARCHAR(25),
IN in_machine_id INT
)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM machine WHERE machine.id = in_machine_id AND machine.available = 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO user_machine VALUES (in_username, in_machine_id);
    UPDATE machine SET machine.available = 0 WHERE machine.id = in_machine_id;
   END IF;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

MySQL error is,

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

What does " near '' " mean? How can I correct this error?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these one useful to you. Actually your missed `DELIMITER //`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_apply(
IN in_username VARCHAR(25),
IN in_machine_id INT
)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM machine WHERE machine.id = in_machine_id AND machine.available = 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO user_machine VALUES (in_username, in_machine_id);
    UPDATE machine SET machine.available = 0 WHERE machine.id = in_machine_id;
   END IF;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Thank you.